# AOSP NFC device call flow from HAL to Application Framework Layer

Tags: android, nfc, android-source

I'm studying the NFC code of Google Pixel AOSP build (android-8.0.0_r3). I can understand the call flow from kernel all the way to Android hardware module `system\nfc\halimpl\pn54x\nfc_nci.c` as following:

```
 struct nfc_nci_module_t HAL_MODULE_INFO_SYM = {
    .common =
        {
            .tag = HARDWARE_MODULE_TAG,
            .module_api_version = 0x0100, /* [15:8] major, [7:0] minor (1.0) */
            .hal_api_version = 0x00,      /* 0 is only valid value */
            .id = NFC_NCI_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID,
            .name = "NXP PN54X NFC NCI HW HAL",
            .author = "NXP Semiconductors",
            .methods = &nfc_module_methods,
        }, 
 };
```

This hardware module is loaded via `hw_get_module(NFC_NCI_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID)` found it in `hardware/interface/nfc/1.0/default/nfc.cpp : HIDL_FETCH_INfc(...)`. Now I'm stuck here unable to find where in the AOSP invoked `HIDL_FETCH_INfc(...)`and how does it link to the next layer?

Comment: To check ANDROID HIDL (HAL interface definition language)

Answer (score 0):

For android services that interact with hardware it connects in the following way.
In the nfc.cpp there should be a functions that are similar to:

```
JNINativeMethod method_table[]= {
    {"external_name","(I)Z)",(void*)internal_name},
};

int register_android_server_FlexcanService(JNIEnv* env)
{
    return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env,"com/android/server/MyService",method_table,NELEM(method_table));
}
```

This jniRegisterNativeMethods is called in onload.cpp and nfc.cpp is added to the Android.mk in the same folder

Then in the java package com.android.server.MyService (core/java/com/android/server) there will be a call to the native function:

```
public static native boolean external_name(int someVar);
```

From there there will be an .aidl binder file to expose the service methods to the SDK and eventually into top level Android apps.

Comment: I do not see any `jniRegisterNativeMethods(...)` in dir `hardware/interface/nfc`

Comment: Do you mean you can't find `jniRegisterNativeMethods` by typing in the terminal: `grep -r jniRegisterNativeMethods` in the hardware/interface/nfc dir?

Comment: Yes tried that, cannot find it in hardware/interface/nfc dir

Comment: Try looking in `~/myandroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/nfc` That appears to be the location of the .aidl binder interfaces.

Comment: I found some `jniRegisterNativeMethods` under packages/apps/Nfc, but I still do not see any of the native methods link to  `HIDL_FETCH_INfc(...)`

Answer (score 0):

In Android 7.x, NFC JNI locates at packages/apps/Nfc/nci/jni/. I haven't checked Android 8.x source, but I think it's still there.

Comment: Yes you are right about the path, but still no answer on how does `HIDL_FETCH_INfc(...)` link with any of the files there?

Comment: You can find 
`hw_get_module(NFC_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID, &hw_module);`
in packages/apps/Nfc/nci/jni/, why do you need `HIDL_FETCH_INfc` ?

Comment: I cant find `hw_get_module(NFC_HARDWARE_MODULE_ID, &hw_module)` in `packages/apps/Nfc/nci/jni/`